# If else statement in Power Query throws error "Token Else expected"

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am pretty new to Power Query

I have two separate Power Querys that work in separate/stand-alone queries, but I want to use an `if` statement that that takes the value of a cell with a checkbox to use either the JSON or the CSV

I have a checkbox in a cell called `useWhat` then two other cells one called `SourceLink` which has a link to a JSON file and another called `fp` which is a local link to a folder with a CSV in it

I have the following statement, but I am getting an error right after the
`SourceLink = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceLink"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],`

the `comma` is highlighted in red.

Any assistance with this If statement is appreciated

Thanks

essentially I am trying to do this

```
let
   #what = 
      if useWhat = "TRUE" then 
         import via JSON
      else
         import via CSV
      end if
      more code
```

what I have

```
let 
    #"what" = 
        if useWhat = "TRUE" then 
           SourceLink = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="sourceLink"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
           Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(sourceLink)),
           Expanded=Table.FromRecords (Source[elements] ),
           #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(Expanded),
           #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Errors", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
           #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
           #"Combine items in list" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Value", each try if Value.Is(_, type list ) then Text.Combine(_,"|") else _ otherwise _, type text}}),
           #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Combine items in list", List.Distinct(#"Combine items in list"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value"),
           #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"}),
           #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns"),each {_,type text}))
        else
           FilePath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="fp"]}[Content]{0}[TheFilePath],
           Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(FilePath),[Delimiter=",", Columns=18, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
           #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}, {"Column12", type text}, {"Column13", type text}, {"Column14", type text}, {"Column15", type text}, {"Column16", type text}, {"Column17", type text}, {"Column18", type text}}),
           #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
            #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),each {_,type text}))
        end if

    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", addMissingEmails}),
    firstColumns = {"Id", "Label", "Email", "Project Name", "Type", "Segment", "Description", "First Name", "Last Name", "Email 2", "Email 3", "Initial Date", "Last Date", "Image"},
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Appended Query",firstColumns & List.RemoveMatchingItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"Appended Query"),firstColumns),MissingField.Ignore),
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Reordered Columns"),
    BulkReplaceStep = fBulkReplace(#"Demoted Headers", MyFindReplace, Table.ColumnNames(#"Demoted Headers")),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(BulkReplaceStep,"#(00A0)","",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(BulkReplaceStep)),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","#(0087)","",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Value")),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Replaced Value1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Label", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{{"Id", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    newMergedHeader = Table.ColumnNames(mergeHeaders){0},
    
    #"Merged Columns" = 
        if newMergedHeader <> null then 
          Table.RenameColumns(
          Table.CombineColumns(#"Trimmed Text",Table.Column(mergeHeaders,newMergedHeader),each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.Difference(List.RemoveNulls(_), {""})),"Merged"),{{"Merged",newMergedHeader}})
        else #"Trimmed Text"
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```

Comment: What is "end if"? That is not a valid PQ statement?

Comment: how does PQ know when the else if at the end of its statement?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but that is not how to write an if statement in M. Additionally, your #"Appended Query" line will probably not work as it isn't referencing a step. You probably need to look at let/in and read some PQ tutorials. I suggest starting here: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/11/17/4107/power-query-m-primer-part1-introduction-simple-expressions-let

Comment: the query works just fine for either the `sourceLink = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceLink"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]` or the `FilePath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="fp"]}[Content]{0}[TheFilePath]` I just can not figure out the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm coding completely blind but you need something like the following:

```
let 
    #"what" = if useWhat = "TRUE" then a else b,
        
    a = let
           SourceLink = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="sourceLink"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
           Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(sourceLink)),
           Expanded=Table.FromRecords (Source[elements] ),
           #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(Expanded),
           #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Errors", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
           #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
           #"Combine items in list" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Value", each try if Value.Is(_, type list ) then Text.Combine(_,"|") else _ otherwise _, type text}}),
           #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Combine items in list", List.Distinct(#"Combine items in list"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value"),
           #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"}),
           #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns"),each {_,type text}))
        in #"Changed Type",
        
        b = let
        
            FilePath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="fp"]}[Content]{0}[TheFilePath],
           Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(FilePath),[Delimiter=",", Columns=18, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
           #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}, {"Column12", type text}, {"Column13", type text}, {"Column14", type text}, {"Column15", type text}, {"Column16", type text}, {"Column17", type text}, {"Column18", type text}}),
           #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
            #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),each {_,type text}))
        in #"Changed Type2",

    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"what", addMissingEmails}),
    firstColumns = {"Id", "Label", "Email", "Project Name", "Type", "Segment", "Description", "First Name", "Last Name", "Email 2", "Email 3", "Initial Date", "Last Date", "Image"},
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Appended Query",firstColumns & List.RemoveMatchingItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"Appended Query"),firstColumns),MissingField.Ignore),
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Reordered Columns"),
    BulkReplaceStep = fBulkReplace(#"Demoted Headers", MyFindReplace, Table.ColumnNames(#"Demoted Headers")),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(BulkReplaceStep,"#(00A0)","",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(BulkReplaceStep)),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","#(0087)","",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Value")),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Replaced Value1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Label", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{{"Id", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    newMergedHeader = Table.ColumnNames(mergeHeaders){0},
    
    #"Merged Columns" = 
        if newMergedHeader <> null then 
          Table.RenameColumns(
          Table.CombineColumns(#"Trimmed Text",Table.Column(mergeHeaders,newMergedHeader),each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.Difference(List.RemoveNulls(_), {""})),"Merged"),{{"Merged",newMergedHeader}})
        else #"Trimmed Text"
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```

Comment: David, thank you. I added `#"useWhat"  = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="useWhat1"]}[Content]{0}[Select CSV or JSON],
    #"what" = if useWhat = "TRUE" then a else b,` to get the value of what.  useWhat shows `TRUE` or `FALSE` correctly but the IF statement is `always` selecting `b`

Comment: What does useWhat evaluate to ? The text string true or the value true ?

Comment: YES, that fixed it I used `true` without the quotes

Comment: David, I searched and tried for hours to get this. Thank you

Comment: Good stuff. Nice work